# How To Unit Test An Application Updater

Tags: c#, unit-testing, auto-update

How would you Unit Test the update process of an application?

I have an application and now I'm writing my own Update module for it (using MVVM) which is a separate EXE. What is the best way to structure this module so that it will be possible to unit test.

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/c-unit-testing-example/2110#2110

Comment: I know how to unit test... im testing all my view models in MVVM, but application updates isn't trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. I am also working on an update application at the moment - I'm using the Microsoft Updater Application Block to allow the application to download updates over http and update itself.

I have designed my application using an Interface-based programming approach to allow me to easily mock implementations to help in unit testing. There's also some very good mocking frameworks available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use

In terms of testing downloading an update, installing it, testing versioning etc. I think a Test Harness might be more appropriate than Unit Tests?

Comment: Could you elaborate on test harness?

Comment: I should have said "Test Harness might be more useful for certain parts". My test harness is a basic win forms app that allows you to configure the updater app. I run it against localhost and download an update and the version numbers of the old and new files are displayed. 

You are right though - it is not trivial to test an updater app and I've been fighting long and hard to get every corner of it tested. I have not thought of a repeatable, independent way to unit test an updater app so I guess I really haven't answered your question at all.